# How to modify content under a devtools panel in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on Google Extension where I am adding new panel to the developer tools and it seems to be working fine for me. But I don't know how to modify the content of the panel through JavaScript.

Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Not for me. May be I am not following it. Actually I want to read header from network request and display content in panel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Displaying content in a panel is not that hard. First, I assume that you've created the base extension (consisting of `manifest.json`, `devtools.html` and `devtools.js`) following [the documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devtools.html). `devtools.html` contains at least `<script src="/devtools.js"></script>`.

When [`chrome.devtools.panel.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devtools.panels.html#method-create) is used to create a panel, a callback can be specified. This callback receives an argument of the type [`ExtensionPanel`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devtools.panels.html#type-ElementsPanel). This object defines the `onShown` and `onHidden` event listeners.
The [`onShown`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devtools.panels.html#event-ExtensionPanel-onShown) event listener receives an additional argument: A reference to the panel's `window` object. Now, you can do anything you wish.

For example, append some text to the panel, when the user opens the devtools panel for the first time:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("devtools Test", "/icon.png", "/panel.html",
  function(extensionPanel) {
    var runOnce = false;
    extensionPanel.onShown.addListener(function(panelWindow) {
        if (runOnce) return;
        runOnce = true;
        // Do something, eg appending the text "Hello!" to the devtools panel
        panelWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello!'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect... Thanks a lot Rob. Listener onShown doesn't work for me since i was trying outside of create function call.