# Communicating between Chrome DevTools and content script in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

(I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661613/chrome-devpanel-extension-communicating-with-background-page) and it didn't work, and I've done a lot of searching and experimentation to no avail.)

I am writing a Chrome extension ([BigConsole](https://github.com/IceCreamYou/Chrome-BigConsole)) with the goal of building a better Console tab for the Chrome developer tools. This means I would like to execute user-input code in the context of the page with access to the DOM and other variables on the page. To do this, the communication is structured as follows:

- `devtools` creates a `panel` where the user writes code
- When the user wants to execute code from the `panel`, the `panel` sends a message to a `background` script with the code
- The `background` script receives the message/code from `panel` and passes it on to the `content` script which is injected into the page
- The `content` script receives the message/code from the `background` script and injects a `script` element into the page which then runs the code
- The result of the `script` on the page is then posted back to the `content` script with window.postMessage
- The `content` script listens for the message/result from the page and passes it on to the `background` script
- The `background` script receives the message/result from the `content` script and passes it on to the `panel`
- The `panel` receives the message/result from the `background` script and inserts it into the log of results

Whew.

Right now, when the user tries to run the code, nothing happens. I put a bunch of `console.log()`s into the code but nothing appears in the console. My main question is, what have I done wrong here with the message passing that results in nothing happening? Alternatively, I would love to be told that I am making this way too complicated and there is a better way of doing things. Simplified code below...

**panel.js:**

```
    window.onload = function() {
      var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "Eval in context"});
      // Add the eval'd response to the console when the background page sends it back
      port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        addToConsole(msg, false);
      });
      document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var s = document.getElementById('console').value;
        try {
          // Ask the background page to ask the content script to inject a script
          // into the DOM that can finally eval `s` in the right context.
          port.postMessage(s);
          // Outputting `s` to the log in the panel works here,
          // but console.log() does nothing, and I can't observe any
          // results of port.postMessage
        }
        catch(e) {}
      });
    };
```

**background.js:**

```
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
      // Listen for message from the panel and pass it on to the content
      port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        // Request a tab for sending needed information
        chrome.tabs.query({'active': true,'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
          // Send message to content script
          if (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message);
          }
        });
      });
      // Post back to Devtools from content
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
        port.postMessage(message);
      });
    });
```

**content.js:**

```
    // Listen for the content to eval from the panel via the background page
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
      executeScriptInPageContext(message);
    });
    function executeScriptInPageContext(m) { alert(m); }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Alex, here's a typo in your code which prevents it from working.

Drop your current code and use [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-eval) to directly run the code and parse the results. This simplifies your complicated logic to:

- devtools creates a panel where the user writes code
- devtools runs code
- devtools handles result

PS. There *is* a way to manipulate the existing console, but I recommend against using it, unless it's for personal use. Two different ways to do this are shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044405/938089).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Bonus points for not just showing me a better way to do this officially, but also a better way to to it unofficially. :)