# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'network' of undefined in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome extension to capture the network tab related data in chrome dev tools.
my code as follows

**manifest.js**

```
{
  "name": "Entries",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Give me entries",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**devtools.js**

```
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function(result) {
  var entries = result.entries; 
  Console.warn("entries : " + entries.length);          
});
```

getting the following error in console tab

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'network' of undefined

Comment: that means `chrome.devtools` is undefined - what is the content of `devtools.html`?

Comment: possibly read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661613/chrome-devpanel-extension-communicating-with-background-page/11677744#11677744

Comment: just an script tag which calls 'devtools.js'  @jaromanda X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not allow user to read the network logs out of the devtools, which means until you run you script in the devtools you aren't able to access the network information.To achieve this you create a new tab in devtools help of panels and run the script in panel.